# app is crashing on second run through of loop with nsnull count

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a loop that works fine the first time through but the second time through the loop I get:

```
-[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3a094a70
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3a094a70'
```

Here is the part in my code where I know it is crashing (the last line):

```
...
NSLog(@"dict::%@",dictForPost);
// collect the photo urls in an array
    photosInDict = [NSArray array];

// photos is an array of dictionaries in the dictionary
photosInDict = dictForPost[@"photos"];
    if (photosInDict.count) {
....
```

I know that when photosInDict doesnt have pictures in the dic it crashes but I dont get why since I initiated the array above it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 photosInDict = dictForPost[@"photos"]
```

*replaces* the object previously allocated and stored in `photosInDict`.
Therefore it does not make sense to allocate the array before. Just

```
NSArray * photosInDict = dictForPost[@"photos"];
```

and then check

```
if ([photosInDict isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // Yes, it is an array. Do something with it.
    if ([photosInDict count]) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The result of `dictForPost[@"photos"];` is giving you an `NSNull` object, not an array.

One option would be this:

```
NSLog(@"dict::%@",dictForPost);
// collect the photo urls in an array

// photos is an array of dictionaries in the dictionary
photosInDict = dictForPost[@"photos"];
if ([photosInDict isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && photosInDict.count) {
```

The line:

```
photosInDict = [NSArray array];
```

is pointless and should be removed.

Comment: I think since it is crashing on the condition of the if statement I need to protect the if with how Martin R showed. Unless an if statement exits if the first condition is not met?

Comment: My `if` statement will work just fine. If the 1st half is false, the 2nd half won't be evaluated. This is called short-circuit evaluation and all C-based languages (as well as many others) use it.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `photosInDict` with an empty array, but then you overwrite it with the dictionary's value for "photos", which just happen to be `NSNull`. You need to check why your dictionary does not have an array for that key.

If the value can be `NSNull` depending on the situation, you must check whether it is an array or not before trying to count or taking some other action.

Comment: No, the value for "photos" is not `null`. It actually has a value and the value is an `NSNull` object.

Comment: Isn't `null` equal to `[NSNull null]`? `NSNull` is the class, while `null` is the instance, right?
But indeed, the error message says `NSNull`.

Comment: Just saying `null` is quite ambiguous. A call to `[NSNull null]` returns an `NSNull` instance, not `null`.